# I am getting error dispatcher is null when trying to implement simple routing using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I add routing with React Router to my React app, it throws error and shows warning:

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Error:

```
dispatcher is null
useRef@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9298:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5616:55
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30071:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33357:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34653:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19663:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19707:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19764:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39638:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38885:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38808:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38781:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38175:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46202:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46180:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46417:25
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ListUsersComponent from './components/ListUsersComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='container'>
        <HeaderComponent />

        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<ListUsersComponent />} />
            <Route path='/admin' element={<ListUsersComponent />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>

        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an issue in React. Have you ensured that all project dependencies are correctly installed? `react-router-dom` appears to be missing from your `package.json` file as a project dependency. Also, you need only one router per app, remove the extraneous `BrowserRouter` from the `App` component since one is already rendered in `index.js`.

Comment: I run npm install react-router-dom@latest --save but react-router-dom not appearing in package.json, should I add manually?

Comment: I addded react-router-dom to package.json and run npm  install, same error

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct directory when installing dependencies, e.g. the project's root directory. I don't any overt issues with the code, so perhaps the issue is external to your UI code. How are you running the app?

Comment: I removed node_modules, added router dependency and run npm install and router started working.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it's working for you now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into a common issue with React Router. The error you're seeing, "Invalid hook call," typically happens when React Router components are nested inside another `BrowserRouter` component.

In your `App.js` file, you have a `BrowserRouter` wrapping the entire component, and then another `BrowserRouter` inside the component. This can cause conflicts.

To fix this, you should have only one `BrowserRouter` at the top level, usually in your `index.js` file. Remove the `BrowserRouter` from the `App` component in `App.js`.

Here's the modified code:

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And in your `App.js`:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import ListUsersComponent from './components/ListUsersComponent';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='container'>
        <HeaderComponent />

        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<ListUsersComponent />} />
            <Route path='/admin' element={<ListUsersComponent />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>

        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Give this a try, and it should resolve the hook-related issue you're facing. If you encounter any more issues or have further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you very much. What  fixed I guess I deleted nodes_modules and tried install everything again. After that it started working.

Comment: Incorrect. There's an invariant check that throws an error if you render a router within another router. It doesn't throw an error with React hooks.

Comment: @AndriusNikulinas It *would* be off-topic for this post, but you are more than welcome to create a new post for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in dependencies I guess. I removed nodes_modules and run npm install. I also added router dependency to package.json